# Using Angular "track by $ index" with pagination, filtering and sorting not working

Tags: angularjs, pagination, filtering, smart-table

I'm having a problem when trying to use the Smart Table with paging, filtering and searching in my table.

I was working with the table when converting a JSON that consumed a request to an object. In this case, I did:

```
$scope.estoque = JSON.parse(data.data);
```

The problem came when I needed to include paging, sorting, and searching. Then using the [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/), which until then had been serving me in what I needed.

In case, to use the functionality of it, my table array can not be object as it was previously, it needs to be JSON. Which in the case has the format below:

```
 $scope.estoqueJSON = data.data;

[
  {
    "EstoqueId": 553,
    "DescricaoEstoque": null,
    "NomeMaterial": "Cabo de Fibra Óptica 04FO Multimodo - Indoor / Outdoor - 62,5/125 Furukawa",
    "CodigoMaterial": "100",
    "Ni": "",
    "QtdMaterial": 3.0,
    "QtdMin": 0.0,
    "Unidade": "m",
    "MaterialId": 1
  }
]
```

Following the tutorial in [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) documentation, I created the table below:

```
<table st-table="estoqueStr" st-set-filter="myStrictFilter" class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                <thead style="text-align:center;">
                    <tr>
                        <th st-sort="CodigoMaterial" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Código</th>
                        <th st-sort="Ni" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Ni</th>
                        <th st-sort="NomeMaterial" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Material</th>
                        <th st-sort="Unidade" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">UNI.</th>
                        <th st-sort="QtdMaterial" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Qtd</th>
                        <th st-sort="QtdMin" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Qtd Min.</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:20px;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="CodigoMaterial" placeholder="Código material" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:20px; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="Ni" placeholder="Ni" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:auto; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="NomeMaterial" placeholder="Nome material" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:10px; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="Unidade" placeholder="Unidade" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:10px; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="QtdMaterial" placeholder="Qtde atual" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:10px; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="QtdMin" placeholder="Qtde mínima" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="" class="">
                    <tr ng-repeat="e in estoqueJSON | filter : paginate | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchField track by $index">
                        <td ng-repeat-start="item in e.value"></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.CodigoMaterial}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.Ni}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.NomeMaterial}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.Unidade}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:right; color:black;">
                            <span e-form="tableform" editable-number="e.QtdMaterial" onbeforesave="checkQtdEstoque(e, $data)">{{item.QtdMaterial}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align-last:right; color:black;" ng-repeat-end>
                            <span editable-number="e.QtdMin" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkQtdMin(e, $data)">{{item.QtdMin}}</span>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I do not know why it's not showing any bug in the console, and also does not display the JSON data in my table. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

AngularJS: 1.3

**UPDATE**

Ero answer was right, I just need to convert again my array for object, and then use ng-repeat. I'm still with Smart Table erro for filter (what doesn't work for object array), but I think it's plugin error and I will check on the github forum.

Comment: Are the items being displayed without the filters on there?

Comment: Good point, I try right now, and not, they aren't displayed. They are displayed if I use JSON.parse to convert in to object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `ng-repeat` is over a single `<tr>` you don't need to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. The encapsulating `<tr>` tag will already repeat the inner HTML of it. Try taking out those tags and only using `item` to reference your current object. I changed the below HTML for you (it's untested!):

```
<tbody id="" class="">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in estoqueJSON | filter : paginate | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchField track by $index">
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.CodigoMaterial}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.Ni}}</td>
        <td>{{item.NomeMaterial}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.Unidade}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right; color:black;">
            <span e-form="tableform" editable-number="item.QtdMaterial" onbeforesave="checkQtdEstoque(item, $data)">{{item.QtdMaterial}}</span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align-last:right; color:black;">
            <span editable-number="item.QtdMin" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkQtdMin(item, $data)">{{item.QtdMin}}</span>
        </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Ero, but this still not working i think this approach was my first try. In the case, the data still not being shown in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Since the objects have unique identifier property, `EstoqueId`, use that for tracking instead of `$index`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in estoqueJSON | filter : paginate | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchField track by e.EstoqueId">
```

From the Docs:

> If you are working with objects that have a unique identifier property, you should track by this identifier instead of the object instance [or `$index`]. Should you reload your data later, `ngRepeat` will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Tracking](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)